# Start zsh with a custom zshrc

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to be able to start zsh with a custom rc file similar to the command: `bash --rc-file /path/to/file`

If this is not possible, then is it possible to start zsh, run `source /path/to/file`, then stay in the same zsh session?

Note: The command `zsh --rcs /path/to/file` does not work, at least not for me...

EDIT:  In its entirety I wish to be able to do the following:
`ssh` to a remote server "example.com", run `zsh`, `source` my configuration located at `/path/to/file`, all in 1 command. This is where I've struggled, especially because I'd rather not write over any configuration files on the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Katz, welcome to unix.SE.  I've edited your question to add some formatting that makes it (slightly) easier to read.  You can click "edit" to see how it works.  I've also removed some extra things, like "Thank you" and your signature (all posts on the Stack Exchange network are automatically signed).

Comment: Thank you, I've now learned how to type `code as such`!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the man pages:

```
STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES
       Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden.  Subsequent  be‐
       haviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the former affects all startup
       files, while the second only affects global startup files (those shown here  with  an
       path starting with a /).  If one of the options is unset at any point, any subsequent
       startup file(s) of the corresponding type will not be read.  It is also possible  for
       a  file  in  $ZDOTDIR  to  re-enable  GLOBAL_RCS.  Both RCS and GLOBAL_RCS are set by
       default.

       Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a  login  shell,  com‐
       mands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is
       interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.  Finally, if
       the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

       When a login shell exits, the files $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout and then /etc/zlogout are read.
       This happens with either an explicit exit via the exit  or  logout  commands,  or  an
       implicit exit by reading end-of-file from the terminal.  However, if the shell termi‐
       nates due to exec'ing another process, the logout files are not read.  These are also
       affected  by  the  RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options.  Note also that the RCS option affects
       the saving of history files, i.e. if RCS is unset when the shell  exits,  no  history
       file will be saved.

       If  ZDOTDIR  is unset, HOME is used instead.  Files listed above as being in /etc may
       be in another directory, depending on the installation.

       As /etc/zshenv is run for all instances of zsh, it is important that it  be  kept  as
       small  as  possible.  In particular, it is a good idea to put code that does not need
       to be run for every single shell behind a test of the form `if [[  -o  rcs  ]];  then
       ...' so that it will not be executed when zsh is invoked with the `-f' option.
```

so you should be able to set the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` to a new directory to get zsh to look for a different set of dotfiles.

As the man page suggests, `RCS` and `GLOBAL_RCS` are not paths to rc files, as you are attempting to use them, but rather options you can enable or disable.  So, for instance, the flag `--rcs` will enable the `RCS` option, causing zsh to read from rc files. You can use the following command-line flags to zsh to enable or disable `RCS` or `GLOBAL_RCS`:

```
  --globalrcs
  --rcs
  -d    equivalent to --no-globalrcs
  -f    equivalent to --no-rcs
```

To answer your other question:

> is it possible to start zsh, run "source /path/to/file", then stay in
>   the same zsh session?

Yes, this is pretty easy according to the above directions.  Just run `zsh -d -f` and then `source /path/to/zshrc`.

Comment: As this does work per my question, I failed to mention that I can only run 1 command. This does not satisfy what I wish to use this for (a custom ssh with my personal configurations). The problem lies in that running `zsh -d -f; source /path/to/file` does not ever execute the second command in the first session of zsh until exiting.

Comment: In its entirety I wish to be able to do the following.

`ssh` to a remote server "example.com", run `zsh`, `source` my configuration located at `/path/to/file`, all in 1 command. This is where I've struggled, especially because I'd rather not write over any configuration files on the remote machine. 

Thank you for you answer though!

Comment: seems like your problem is not in using a custom zshrc but in not knowing how to use a shell over ssh.  If you run `ssh host "zsh -d -f; source /path/to/file"`, then ssh will run first `zsh` on the remote host, then `source ...` after the zsh shell exits.  Instead what you want to do is `ssh -t host zsh -d -f` to drop into an interactive shell on the remote host, or if you don't want an interactive shell, do `ssh host zsh -d -f -c \"source /path/to/file\; other command\; ... \"`.

Comment: No I understand how ssh works with interactive shells. The problem is that running `ssh -t host "zsh -d -f; source /path/to/file` drops me into an interactive (and barren) `zsh` shell.

Comment: I already told you why this is and how to fix it. When you run `ssh -t host "zsh -d -f; source /path/to/file"`, the command `source...` is NOT run inside the zsh shell. It's run in your login shell after the zsh shell exits. To test this out, run `ssh host "zsh; echo foo"`. You will see the output "foo" *after* you exit from the zsh shell.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I don't want a login shell, I want interactive with the source command rum automatically. Unfortunately this seems to be difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do both, though you should be able to figure this out by reading the `INVOCATION` section of the zsh man pages. However, you can just set `ZDOTDIR` instead: `ssh -t host ZDOTDIR=/path/to/rcfile zsh`

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I want to leave as little trace as possible. I could write a logout script that puts the `ZDOTDIR` back to what it was originally, but I want there to be an obvious solution. Why is it that zsh is on par and better than bash in all cases except for a simple task? It's just silly...

Comment: @Le_Katz, `ZDOTDIR=x zsh` only sets `ZDOTDIR` for that `zsh` process (it adds `ZDOTDIR=x` to the environment that that `zsh` receives), there's nothing to _put back_ after that `zsh` has exited (and `.zlogout` is only evaluated for login shells) you might still want to _unset_ ZDOTDIR from within your startup scripts if you don't want other zsh instanced called by that `zsh` to inherit it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Woohoo! Thank you for clarifying! This works splendidly :D

Comment: Any idea how to find `--no-globalrcs` in the manpages? `man zshall` doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat I don't see `--no-globalrcs` mentioned explicitly in the man pages, but `-d` is described in `man 1 zshoptions`, and `zsh --help` mentions that the two options are equivalent.

Comment: @jayhendren jooc how did you discover `--no-globalrcs` and `--no-rcs`?  I can't find it documented in the man page.  I can only find it hinted to in the [source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Azsh-users%2Fzsh%20globalrcs&type=code).

Comment: @MaxCoplan I answered that question in my previous comment in this thread.

Answer (score 6):

while with ZDOTDIR, you can tell `zsh` to interpret a file called `.zshrc` in any directory of your choosing, having it interpret any file of your choosing (not necessarily called `.zshrc`) proves quite difficult.

In `sh` or `ksh` emulation, `zsh` evaluates `$ENV`; so you could add `emulate zsh` at the top of your `/path/to/file` and do:

```
ssh -t host 'zsh -c "ARGV0=sh ENV=/path/to/file exec zsh"'
```

Another very convoluted approach could be:

```
ssh -t host 'PS1='\''${${functions[zsh_directory_name]::="
    set +o promptsubst
    unset -f zsh_directory_name
    unset PS1
    . /path/to/file
 "}+}${(D):-}${PS1=%m%# }'\' exec zsh -o promptsubst -f
```

That one deserves a bit of an explanation.

`${foo::=value}` is a variable expansion that actually *sets* `$foo`. `$functions` is a special associative array that maps function names to their definitions.

With the `promptsubst` option, variables in `$PS1` are expanded. So, upon the first prompt, the variables in that PS1 will be expanded.

The `zsh_directory_name` function is a special function that helps expanding the `~foo` to `/path/to/something` and the reverse. That's used for instance with `%~` in the prompt so that if the current directory is `/opt/myproj/proj/x` you can display it as `~proj:x` by having `zsh_directory_name` do the mapping `proj:x` <=> `/opt/myproj/proj/x`. That's also used by the `D` parameter expansion flag. So if one expands `${(D)somevar}`, that `zsh_directory_name` function will be called.

Here, we're using `${(D):-}`, `${:-}`, that is `${no_var:-nothing}` expands to `nothing` if `$no_var` is empty, so `${(D):-}` expands to nothing while calling `zsh_directory_name`. `zsh_directory_name` has previously been defined as:

```
zsh_directory_name() {
  set +o promptsubst
  unset -f zsh_directory_name
  unset PS1; . /path/to/file
}
```

That is, upon the first PS1 expansion (upon the first prompt), `${(D):-}` will cause the `promptsubst` option to be unset (to cancel the `-o promptsubst`), `zsh_directory_name()` to be undefined (as we want to run it only once) `$PS1` to be unset, and `/path/to/file` to be sourced.

`${PS1=%m%# }` expands (and assigns `$PS1`) to `%m%#` unless PS1 was already defined (for instance by `/path/to/file` after the `unset`), and `%m%#` happens to be the default value of `PS1`.

Comment: This looks quite extravagant and I will give it a try as soon as possible. I'm hopeful this works!

Comment: The emulate trick is cool and simple. Hope it does not have any side effects