# How do I invoke Zsh and skip .zshrc or .zshenv?

Tags: zsh, dot-files

How do I invoke Zsh interactively while asking it to *not* process `.zshrc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start zsh with a custom zshrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131716/start-zsh-with-a-custom-zshrc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
zsh --no-rcs
```

The `--no-rcs` option disables the `RCS` shell option in `zsh`.  This prevents the shell from reading *any* other startup file than `/etc/zshenv` (this file can not be ignored).